# How to Set up SOAP Request via ASP.NET to url as a service?

Tags: asp.net, soap, httpwebrequest

Have the following code in my Default.aspx file, located at `http://localhost/idss/Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Testing IDSS Return Values</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@

// how we do it
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("idss/requests/categoryList.xml"));

// create the request to your URL
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/idss/Default.aspx");

// add the headers
// the SOAPACtion determines what action the web service should use
// YOU MUST KNOW THIS and SET IT HERE
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx/GetCategoryList");

// set the request type
// we use utf-8 but set the content type here
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";

// add our body to the request
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
doc.Save( stream );
stream.Close();

// get the response back
using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     request.Write(response);
}//end using


 %>
</body>

</html>
```

The xml file located at:  `http://localhost/idss/requests/categoryList.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizeHeader xmlns="http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx">
      <UserName>MyUsername</UserName>
      <Password>MyPassword</Password>
    </AuthorizeHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCategoryList xmlns="http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Where `MyUsername` and `MyPassword` is filled in with the correct username and password.  The URL located here:  http://ws.idssasp.com/members.asmx?op=GetCategoryList&pn=0 tells me that SOAP should send a request like this:

```
POST /members.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.idssasp.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx/GetCategoryList"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizeHeader xmlns="http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthorizeHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCategoryList xmlns="http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But when I browse to `http://localhost/idss/Default.aspx` I get an Internal Server Error (500).  What exactly am I doing wrong here?  Do I need to add namespaces?  Or other References somewhere in the Default.aspx file?  If so, which one's are needed?  Also, am I pointing to the correct in `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/idss/Default.aspx");`?

Am I doing this correctly?  I just feel like something is missing here.

Comment: Don't do SOAP by hand. Use "Add Service Reference". See [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response.  The service already exists and I do not have access to the service, only have access to the service via SOAP, from urls and such.  Not sure how that url helps since it wants me to create a service, so it seems.

Comment: The article only creates a service to use as an example. The article is more about how to consume a service.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - So for my situation, I should skip the creation of the "WCF Service Application" step?  And go right to "Creating a Simple Client"?

Comment: Yes. The creation of the service is for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: But "Creating the Client" is a Console Application, not a website.  I will be needing a website to connect to the service...

Comment: It is done in exactly the same way for web application projects. Are you using a web site "project" (File->New Web Site)? I think that's the same, but I always recommend that nobody use those, so I don't know for certain.

Comment: Ok, gotcha... I managed to get the Service loaded now, but can't figure out how to use it...  Blah... arggg!

Comment: Keep reading the article. It discusses how to use the service. In particular, it tells you how to discover the names and parameters of all service operations.

Comment: Yeah, I see that.  In the Object Browser for the Service, it says a ton of types in there, like `GetCategoryListRequest`, `GetCategoryListResponse`, pretty much all types in there have a Request and a Response (text appended to them), but I don't know how to use it...